# PC not synchronizing time automatically with NTP Server (Centos 6)

Tags: linux, centos, ntp

I'm trying to configure a remote machine to synchronize with my NTPServer without success...

It only works when I run ntpdate SERVER_NAME, but it doesn't synchronize automatically.

I have stopped iptables in both server and pc. In my /etc/ntp.conf file I have "server SERVER_NAME iburst".

Any idea of what can be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a cron job schedule the synchronization by way of ntpdate, by adding a line to your root crontab like so:

```
5  * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate your.ntpserver.com
```